# Add function with parameters to Flask's teardown_appcontext

Tags: python, flask

I would like to add a Class' `__exit()__` method to the list of functions that are called when Flask's `app.teardown_appcontext()` is called.

I know that this can be done for a function (e.g., `close_database()`) that has no parameters such as:

```
app.teardown_appcontext(close_database)
```

But how do I do this for a function (e.g., `__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, traceback)`) which takes arguments. Doing the below results in an error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.

```
    app.teardown_appcontext(display.__exit__(None, None, None))
```

For context my `init_app()` looks like the following, which presenets the above error:

```
def init_app():
app = Flask(__name__)

database.init_app(app)
display = Display(mode='s')

app.teardown_appcontext(display.__exit__(None, None, None))

with app.app_context():
    from . import routes
    database.init_database()
    display.__enter__()
    return app
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Problem

Writing `app.teardown_appcontext(display.__exit__(None, None, None))` actually calls `display.__exit__` then use the return value to be passed to `app.teardown_appcontext` (which is None so the error), that isn't what you want

##### Solve

Use a lambda, that does the same as your intermediate `close_database` method, but lighter

```
app.teardown_appcontext(lambda: display.__exit__(None, None, None))
```